# powershell wrapping long file paths

Tags: powershell

i have a script running fine in a powershell window but not when ran as a script, where lines are "wrapped", screwing the variables contents.

basically a part of my code looks like this :

```
Get-AIPFileStatus -Path $Path | Where-Object {$_.IsRMSProtected -eq 'True'}  | Out-String -Stream -width 4096 | Select-String "^(FileName|FilePath) +: +(.*)$"
```

and instead of getting an output such as this one :

```
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name01.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name02.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name03.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name04.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_nameN.xlsx
```

the script instead generates :

```
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name01.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name02.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name03.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name04.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_nameN.xlsx
```

which is messing up my loop afterwards (as i need the full file name), e.g. my code :

```
Get-AIPFileStatus -Path $Path | Where-Object {$_.IsRMSProtected -eq 'True'} | Out-String -Stream -width 4096 | Select-String "^(FileName|FilePath) +: +(.*)$" | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value} |
Foreach-Object {
   $file = $_
   Write-Host -NoNewline "File '$file' has encryption enabled, trying to remove it.."
   Set-AIPFileLabel -LabelId $UID -Path $file -PreserveFileDetails -JustificationMessage "blablabla" 
   if( $? ) {
      Write-Host "SUCCESS"
   } else {
      Write-Host "FAILED"
   }
}
```

**the variable "$file" above is only getting a small piece of the file path.**
in short, i just want to get file paths from the output of Get-AIPFileStatus and apply something on them, but because of this wrapping this is messing up the script as the final result is that the file path "taken" from the script is for example :

```
Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_her
```

instead of :

```
Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name01.xlsx
```

how can i fix that ?
thanks again
regards,

PS : this is my first ever powershell script, be nice :)

Comment: Using string method : $str = "Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name01.xlsx"
$result = $str.Substring(0, $str.LastIndexOf('\'))
Write-Host $result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. The solutions you offered seemed quite complex while i was simply trying to understand why the "basic" command Get-AIPFileStatus did wrap the paths and it was apparently related to the loop i was doing using ForEach-Object.

I have replaced it with ForEach instead and it is working now :

```
 Get-AIPFileStatus -Path $Path | Where-Object {$_.IsRMSProtected -eq 'True'} | Out-String -Stream -width 4096 | Select-String "^(FileName|FilePath) +: +(.*)$" | ForEach {
   $encryptedfile = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
   # using $encryptedfile...
}
```

i don't really know why but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
$txt = @"
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name01.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name02.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name03.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_name04.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\
file_nameN.xlsx
"@

$Splitted = ($txt -split "\n")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $Splitted.Count; $i+=2)
{
$Splitted[$i..($i-1)]  -join ""
}
```

Will Results:

```
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_nameN.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name01.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name02.xlsx
FileName        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name03.xlsx
FilePath        : Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name04.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

You might [PinVoke](https://www.leeholmes.com/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough) the [Create pagepathcompactpathex (shlwapi)](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.pathcompactpathex) function:

```
$Shlwapi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]public static extern bool PathCompactPathEx([Out] System.Text.StringBuilder pszOut, string szPath, int cchMax, int dwFlags);
' -Name 'ShlwapiFunctions' -namespace ShlwapiFunctions -PassThru

$Path = 'Z:\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\long_path_here\file_name01.xlsx'
$Length = 33 # Size of the simplifyed path (+1)
$StringBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new($Length) 
$Null = $Shlwapi::PathCompactPathEx($StringBuilder, $Path, $Length, 0)
$StringBuilder.ToString()

Z:\long_path...\file_name01.xlsx
```